# How to add support for new platform for react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Let's say I have platform X which has javascript runtime and I want to let developers use react-native to build applications for that platform. Maybe my google is broken but I can't find good documentation on what interfaces or other abstractions I need to implement to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at react-native-web, react-native-windows, and react-native-macros as examples.

Basic principle is to add a wrapper translation layer around all components related to React-Native. Third party libs are typically ignored.

Also make sure to reference metro docs. There is a section for adding additional extensions. That's probably what you want in this case.

[Metro#platforms](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration#platforms)